# Loading rasters from a GeoPackage into QGIS modeler based on attribute information?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage

I am looking to load raster layers from a GeoPackage based on strings of attribute information that is stored in a field. The process I am looking for is as follows:

- Site Boundary created before the model is used as a model input.
- 10km Tile (OS data) ready for use as a model input.

  1. Buffer of site boundary to create generate area of interest to select tiles.
  2. Intersection of buffer with 10km tiles generates attribute information for 'Tile name'
  3. 'Load layer into project' - identifies multiple tiles based on 'Tile name' to add to the project.

[image: QGIS model]

I am stuck with getting the 'Load layer into project' to add layers from a GeoPackage and have not been able to achieve this even for an individual raster layer in a GeoPackage.

I am using QGIS version 3.8