# QGIS Naming Model Outputs using attribute from input layer

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, model, rename, qgis-modeler

This is the first QGIS Process Model I have ever attempted to build (and I am still on a learning curve with QGIS generally).

**THE ASSIGNMENT:**

I need to build a model that will take an input vector and (1) rename it (the name must come from an attribute value stored within the layer), (2) clip it against another polygon, (3) and finally add a pre-defined style.

**THE CATCH:**

The input layers will always have the same name i.e. "2D Zones" there is no way around this as they are outputs from another piece of software and this cannot be changed. The fields for these input layers will always have the same names and will be arranged in the same order, the attribute values will differ.

There is a field within each "2D Zones" table called "retperiod" the value appearing in that column will be the same throughout the whole column but will differ from layer to layer, so this is the attribute I want to use as a name.

**BACKGROUND READING:**

After reading the solutions to similar problems posted here:

- [Create dynamic filename, based on attribute value, for output of QGIS model](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440339/create-dynamic-filename-based-on-attribute-value-for-output-of-qgis-model/440341#440341)
- [Create dynamic filename, based on attribute value, for output of QGIS model](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440339/create-dynamic-filename-based-on-attribute-value-for-output-of-qgis-model)
- [Accessing input layer properties from QGIS Modeler?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268541/accessing-input-layer-properties-from-qgis-modeler)

I have managed to come up with a model that performs the task I wish it to do (see link).

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y0RnrLsOQIHaiDn74U8Qsana1iBUyoM8?usp=sharing

I have also read all this lot (although probably haven't understood it all):

- [QGIS graphical modeller naming layer output based on attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408504/qgis-graphical-modeller-naming-layer-output-based-on-attribute)
- [Loading rasters from a GeoPackage into QGIS modeler based on attribute information?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329059/loading-rasters-from-a-geopackage-into-qgis-modeler-based-on-attribute-informati)
- [QGIS Modeler: Layer Rename does not output](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366484/qgis-modeler-layer-rename-does-not-output)
- [Rename layer in model builder with almost original name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434172/rename-layer-in-model-builder-with-almost-original-name)
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39874
- [Is it possible to have dynamic layer names in QGIS project?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131597/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-layer-names-in-qgis-project)

**THE PROBLEM**

However, one shortcoming of my model is that I have to specify the input layers as both a "Vector Features" and a "Vector Layer" input. This seems to be because I can only the Modeller won't allow the "get_feature_by_id" function to work on the "vector layer" input but it will work on the "vector feature" input..... Essentially, this model will only complete the renaming routine, i.e. this bit:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id(@vectorfeature,1),'retperiod')
```

If I get it to look in the "vector feature" input for the attribute that can be used as a name but then it must be applied to the input from "vector layer" in order for the subsequent processes (i.e. clipping and styling) to work.

All very unintuitive.

**THE QUESTION:**

Is there a more elegant solution to all this whereby I don't have to specify the same inputs twice in two different ways?

This is still problematic as the original files all have exactly the same name and there is every chance I will match the two inputs incorrectly when using the "batch process" option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Rename Layer` algorithm, set the `New name` input to `Pre-calculated Value` and insert an expression that gets the value of the attribute `retperiod` from the input layer. The input layer is available as a context variable in the expression string builder.

The expression to use looks like:

```
attribute (get_feature_by_id (@load_vector_layer, 1),'retperiod')
```

[image]

Comment: If I were to implement your suggestion I could use the "rename" algorithm as soon as the input vector is added to the model: no point in this as the clipping procedure requires the output to be renamed "clipped" unless you re-specify a name. Logically then, I could do it on the model output.... not so;

Comment: "attribute (get_feature_by_id (@load_vector_layer, 1),'retperiod')" doesn't seem to work on vector _layers_ only on _vector objects_ (please see third hyperlink on my original post). This is very much the source of my confusion as your suggested solution looks logical, but in practice; the "attribute()" statement just returns "NULL" and the model fails on this basis.

Comment: I think the difference between what you did with your previous example (i.e. first hyperlink: which I am trying to copy) and what I am doing is that your model _might_ be referring to a saved layer that you have downloaded with some fixed address, my model is trying to rename a virtual layer that is output from an algorithm and thus not saved. (possibly??).

Comment: OK, I see I was maybe referring to another case. Just renaming the layer this way worked in my case, with the expression provided.

Comment: Well thanks for your input anyway! :-) I really can't understand why your solution _doesn't_ work in my case to be honest. I can see that QGIS seems to point blank refuse to use "@input vector layer"  but is happy enough with "@input vector feature" but I have no idea _why_ this is the case.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing 100% the same as my screenshot - maybe there is a difference you miss....?

Comment: Frustratingly there is no way for me to post a picture. I have posted the model plus some example data at this hyperlink. If you have time to look at it and try making the change yourself you might be able to see what I mean. I don't believe I have made a syntax error or not copied the example properly; QGIS makes it clear when there is a problem of that kind. The model runs just fine when I rename using _@vectorfeature_ as the place to look for an attribute to use as a name, just not when I use _@vectorlayer_

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y0RnrLsOQIHaiDn74U8Qsana1iBUyoM8

Comment: In your example, you should rename the expression using `@inputvectorlayer`: `attribute(get_feature_by_id( @inputvectorlayer,1),'retperiod')` Still, I'm not exactly sure what the model should achieve (what should I set as input, what should the output look like).

Comment: So this is the root of the confusion: I have tried renaming the expression as you suggest but the expression returns "NULL" and the renaming therefore fails. I think it might be because "@inputvectorlayer" would require referring to the _file itself_ e.g. C:\users\QGIS\vectorlayer.gpkg instead of the _model input_ (I am guessing). The model is to clip some Hydraulic Model results (vectors all named 2dZones) with a boundary polygon, each clipped output is then named after the value found in the "retperiod" column (e.g 10, 50, 200) then a style is applied to show flood depth. Nothing complicated